# Using esc_url_raw with protocols properly

Tags: urls, sanitization

I'm trying to build up my own function to sanitize a URL before saving it to my WP database. However I cannot get esc_url_raw to trigger against unwanted protocols. The function below is letting all protocols through.

```
function scientifik_sanitize_url($url){
    $prots = array('http', 'https');
    $item  = $url;

    $sanitized = esc_url_raw( $item, $prots );
    if ( is_wp_error( $sanitized ) ) {
        return 'funny';
        die();
    }

    return $item;

};
```

I appreciate anyone's experience with this function in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are execpeting a [WP Error object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) if the URL has a non-valid protocol but `esc_url_raw` returns an empty string in that case (see [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw#Return_Values)), not a WP Error object. So, `is_wp_error( $escaped )` never verifies. Also, you are checking an undefined `$escaped` variable (note that the value of `esc_url_raw` is stored in `$sanitized` variable):

```
function scientifik_sanitize_url($url){

    $prots = array('http', 'https');
    $item  = $url;

    $escaped = esc_url_raw( $item, $prots );
    if ( empty( $escaped ) ) {
        return 'funny';
        die();
    }

    return $item;

};
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you very much @Cybmeta. Sometimes at the end of the day you just make dumb moves... Also the codex has an example utilizing the WP Error Object.

Comment: Yeah, I know, all of us feel that from time to time. Note that the example in codex using wp error object is for the result of `wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );`